# Rectifying a Tiff Given One Corner Coordinate

Tags: python, gdal, remote-sensing, exif

I'm trying to rectify an image that I don't know much about other than the coordinate of the southwest corner, which I was able to pull using ExifTool.

Is there any programming solution to identifying the coordinates of the other 3 corners and using that data to warp the image?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  In this situation you would also require the pixel size (resolution) in both x and y direction, as well as the rotation factor.

The [World file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) is a good example of providing metadata to support display of 'plain' imagery with no explicit GIS innards.